# Difference between substitution and original function var

Tags: javascript

Thank you for help. Sorry for not knowing the exact name of the concept I'm using.

I have a function like this.

```
var counter = function() {
  var count = 0;
  function changeCount(number) {
    count += number; 
  }
  return {
    increase: function() {
      changeCount(1);
    },
    decrease: function() {
      changeCount(-1);
    },
    show: function() {
      alert(count);
    }
  }
};
```

Now, I'm gonna make '3' with this function, and there seems two ways.

1)

```
counter().increase()
counter().increase()
counter().increase()
counter().show()
```

I guessed this would throw out '3', but the answer was '0'.

2)

```
var another = counter();
another.increase();
another.increase();
another.increase();
another.show()
```

Now it returns '3' for answer.
And here's my question. Literally, the variable "another" is just the same with "counter()". 
Then, WHY the answers come different?

The former code (counter().increase() ) seems to return 'count' back to 'o' after every 3 lines of 'counter().increase()'. 
Whereas 'another.increase()' seems to cumulate the change of variable 'count'. 
 The difference between two codes is just saying "variable 'another' is the same with counter()". And why is this leading to such different answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what the counter function does.

It creates a variable, sets it to 0, then returns some functions.

If you call counter once, it does that once. If you call it three times, it does that three times.

(and then you call `.increase()` on the return value … and in your first example that's the *three different things* but in the second, it is the same thing each time).

---

Or to put it another way.

If, every time you called `counter` you took a clean sheet of paper and put it down in front of you. And every time you called `increase` you drew a tick on the piece of paper in front of you.

You'd either end up with three pieces of paper with a tick on each, or one piece of paper with three ticks.

Comment: Thank you for comment. However Isn't it same to the variable 'another' ?
Each time I call 'another', it will call 'counter' function, and do the same thing each time. Creates var,  sets it to 0. But the answer is 'not the same'. Then why?

Comment: @yubin — You **never** *call* `another`. It is `another` not `another()`. (And since `another` is not a function, if you did `another()`, it would throw an exception). `another` is just the piece of paper sitting in front of you, it isn't the set of instructions to get a new piece of paper.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

I see this has already been answered, but for clarification (and because I've already typed it):

Your `counter` returns a new object every time, each with its own function declarations (increase, decrease, show). So each time you call counter() you're getting a new independent instance of that object, and its functions don't exist outside the *scope* of that instance.

so:

```js
// this:
counter().increase();

// is the equivalent of this:
const c1 = counter();
c1.increase();

// and if you do it repeatedly:
counter().increase(); // new instance
counter().increase(); // new instance
counter().increase(); // new instance
counter().show(); // new instance

// you're effectively doing:
const c1 = counter();
c1.increase();

const c2 = counter();
c2.increase();

const c3 = counter();
c3.increase();

const c4 = counter();
c4.show();

// whereas this calls increase() three times on the same object:
const another = counter();
another.increase();
another.increase();
another.increase();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

May be it's just difference of using '( ) ' .   '( )' means you're gonna execute (or open) the variable or function before the bracket.

Adjust the codes a little like this

```
var counter = (function() {
  var count = 0;
  function changeCount(number) {
    count += number; 
  }
  return {
    increase: function() {
      changeCount(1);
    },
    decrease: function() {
      changeCount(-1);
    },
    show: function() {
      alert(count);
    }
  }
})();
counter.increase()
counter.increase()
counter.increase()
counter.show()
```

Then it returns '3'. The only difference is the use of "()".
If you don't use '()', it mean you're not gonna execute it. So you can just handle already opened context.